# How to create a random string of random length

Tags: random

I'm looking for a way to create a string of random letters and random
length. So whenever the command is used I get different strings.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\randomstring}{...}

\begin{document}
\randomstring
\randomstring

\end{document}
```

The out put could be

xkakhiw

or

khaggfpze

I think you got the idea. Could someone give me a hint, where to start?

Comment: Any limit to the length of the strings?

Comment: A random number between 1 and a maximum determines the length (the maximum is necessary). A random number between 1 and 26 determines a letter (with `\ifcase`). This process repeated *n* times gives you the desired string (where *n* is the length, determined in the first step). I'm not sure, but I think to generate a random number (with pdfTeX at least) there is `\pdfuniformdeviate` but I don't know its syntax.

Comment: @egreg: any number between 1 and 26.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Manuel's idea:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomstring}{}
 {
  \randomstring_make:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defrandomstring}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\cs_set:Npe}{\cs_new:Npe} #2 { \randomstring_make: }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setrandomstringlength}{m}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_randomstring_length_int { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_randomstring_length_int

\cs_new:Nn \randomstring_make:
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \int_rand:n { \l_randomstring_length_int } }
   {
    \int_to_alph:n { \int_rand:n { 26 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setrandomstringlength{26}

\begin{document}

\randomstring

\randomstring

\randomstring

\defrandomstring{\foo}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\setrandomstringlength{4}

\randomstring

\randomstring

\defrandomstring*{\foo}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

With `\setrandomstringlenght` we set the upper bound to the length of the strings. A random integer between 1 and this upper bound (inclusive) is chosen and as many letters are randomly generated using `\int_to_alph:n { \int_rand:n { 26 } }`.

With `\defrandomstring` we can store a random string in a macro. The variant `\defrandomstring*` doesn't check whether the macro is already defined (use with care).

This works with any engine.

[image]

See edit history for a previous version.

Comment: Pretty easy syntax for that primitive. I didn't know.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, very handy.

Comment: @egreg: This is great. So I have to switch to lualatex?

Comment: @schmendrich If you're using XeLaTeX, it's possible to do the same, but not in an expandable way. Do you need it?

Comment: @egreg: I have to admit I have no clue what "expandable way" means :( Could you also provide a solution for xelatex? Why must xelatex have a different solution from the lualatex solution?

Comment: @schmendrich With "expandable” I mean something that can be generated and stored in a control sequence like I did for `\foo`; if you just need to print a random sequence (or also store it in a control sequence, but using an indirect way) I'll show how in a short time.

Comment: @egreg: wow, this is great. I like your package solution. Will walk through the code and try to understand it. It's a pleasure to learn from people like you.

Comment: @egreg I found this in early 2024. The packaged solution works in lualatex, but it is necessary to change `\pdfuniformdeviate` to `\uniformdeviate` due to changes made a few years ago.

Comment: @rallg Oh, nowadays we can do it in an engine independent way. Revamped.

Comment: @egreg Nice edit. Amazing.